# Bootstrap modal window loop through after some delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap modal window, it is working fine. But i want it to loop through after some delay even the user close the pop up as many times...

```
$(window).load(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('#myCounter').modal('show');
   }, 5000);
});
```

How can i make it loop after every 5 seconds?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
  function function_name(){
             setTimeout(function(){
               $('#myCounter').modal('show');
             function_name(); // call function
           }, 5000);
        }       
 $(window).load(function(){
        function_name();    
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The setInterval() method will help you to loop and it will continue to call the function until clearInterval() function is called, or the window is closed.

you can try the code attached below:

```
 $(window).load(function(){setInterval(function () { $('#myModal').modal('show');},2000);});
```